# Complication placeholder not showing

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I've just added a complication to my watchOS app. I was able to select it on simulator's watch face, but it shows blank items. Temporary all methods of `CLKComplicationDataSource` return `nil`. I've created a new assets group for complication, added all required **.png** images as specified [here,](https://developer.apple.com/watchos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/) setup Complication Group property in Xcode target, but nothing shows up!

What should I do to enable static placeholder images for my complications?

Configuration in Xcode:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the *.xcassets* file with placeholder images *must* be included into the *watch extension* bundle, but it was included into the watch app instead. I spend all day trying to figure this out.

Comment: Hello kelin could you show me the code that you use to display an image?

Comment: Hi @unixb0y! No code was involved. Just default placeholder images.

Comment: @unixb0y, the system shows them. [Read here](https://developer.apple.com/watchos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/). _"Every complication must provide a set of static images to act as placeholders when the system has no other content to display for your complication’s data."_

Comment: Thank you, on project creation my watch app had the complications folder in the assets already so i placed them there as well. What a painful few hours